# codeigniter (defined(basepath)) error generate while login

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please see the below code segment . I wanted to stop direct access into loginauth function .So i modified my code as below and when I try to direct access it echo the error. But the problem is that when I try to login via login page it also generate the same error . Could anyone can help me please.

```
public function loginauth()
{
    if (defined('base_url')) {
        $this->load->model('Employ_model');
        $this->Employ_model->loginauth();
        $count = $this->db->affected_rows();

        if (($this->session->userdata('privilages')) && ($this->session->userdata('id')) && ($count > 0)) {
            redirect('admin/appliedJobs');

        } else if (($this->session->userdata('id')) && ($count > 0)) {
            redirect('admin/jobsactive');
        } else {
            $this->login();
        }

    } else {
        echo "
        <script>
        alert('Direct access not allowed');
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/hr/hr/index.php/admin/jobsactive';
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Errors you say?

Comment: In CI as far as I know `base_url` is a function not a constant (and as such wont be defined).  So the correct thing would be `function_exists`, but I am not sure why that is even there?  The other way I see it is in `$config['base_url']` but not as a constant by default.  Of course you could add it to `constants.php` but whatever.